# Выделение элемента пазла

Tags: jquery, css

Необходимо изогнуть элемент ввиде пазла (т.е. что бы ). Какие инструменты можно для этого использовать? Вполне возможно, что на флеше это проще будет сделать, но хотелось бы найти реализацию для jQuery/JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я так понимаю, необходимо выйти за рамки стандартных прямоугольных элементов?
Я однажды задавал подобный вопрос. Мне предложили посмотреть на `raphael framework`.
[Демо](http://htmlbook.ru/example/raphael/).
Статья: [Построение интерактивной карты с Raphaël](http://htmlbook.ru/blog/postroenie-interaktivnoi-karty-s-raphael).